# Postgresql custom expression with QueryDSL

Tags: java, postgresql, querydsl

I have a trouble with writing custom boolean template for where clause using QueryDSL. Simply I need to use arraycontains function to know that table.languages contains values at array of strings from filter.

Why Hibernate can't execute this? The raw sql is fine.

Code (variables are simplified, on screenshot it will be different):

```java
    final var test = new JPAQuery<>(this.entityManager)
               .select(table)
               .from(table)
               .where(whereFromFilter(filter))
               .fetch()
    //...some code
    private static Predicate[] whereFromFilter(final Filter filter) {
      final var result = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
      //...some code
      result.add(
                Expressions.booleanTemplate(
                    "arraycontains(replace(replace(({0})::text,'[','{'),']','}')::text[],string_to_array({1},',')) = true",
                    table.languages,
                    "'" + String.join(",", filter.languages) + "'"
                )
      );
      //...some code
      return result.toArray(Predicate[]::new);
    }
```

table.languages in DB it's a json object that simply array of strings (so in template I'm converting it to array of strings):

[image: table.languages]

I also try this code in raw sql console and it works fine:

```
SELECT arraycontains(replace(replace((table.languages)::text,'[','{'),']','}')::text[],string_to_array('CONFIG,PYTHON', ',')) is true
FROM table
```

[image: screenshot of sql-query result]

Another filter (not with custom boolean template) works fine:

```java
result.add(table.issueCountHigh.goe(filter.issueCountHighMin));
```

In debug mode I see that code from custom filter looks similar to code from another filter (that 100% works):

[image]

So, what HqlBaseParser can't parse? SQL functions?

stacktrace:

```
{
"statusCode": 500,
"statusDescription": "Internal Server Error",
"stacktrace": "java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4770)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1090)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3866)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3703)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3570)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3197)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:682)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2959)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2815)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2774)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2685)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2645)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2323)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.exprList(HqlBaseParser.java:4404)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4763)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1090)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3866)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3703)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3570)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3197)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:682)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2959)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2815)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2774)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2685)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2645)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2323)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.exprList(HqlBaseParser.java:4404)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4763)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1090)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3866)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3703)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3570)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3197)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:682)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2959)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2815)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2774)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2685)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2645)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2323)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2071)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.whereClause(HqlBaseParser.java:540)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:831)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:336)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:200)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:294)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.createQuery(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:315)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.createQuery(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:101)\n\tat com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:94)\n\tat com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.fetch(AbstractJPAQuery.java:201)\n\tat
```

Comment: If you want to execute raw SQL, shouldn't you be using `JPASQLQuery`, rather than `JPAQuery`? JPQL is a different language than SQL, although "heavily inspired by SQL".

Comment: @scrhartley the problem is that I've already a lot of code in JPAQuery that work fine and I've a trouble only with this part of code. May exist a way to write it correctly?

Comment: What version of QueryDSL are you using?

Comment: @scrhartley 4.1.4

Comment: Does this question about String literals seem relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887678/querydsl-case-expression-with-string-value

Comment: @scrhartley no, you can see the last screenshot from my question (debug mode), literals looks fine. Also stacktrace have NPE, so it's a bit different

Comment: Do you map table.languages to a String[] and it becomes an ArrayPath in the Q class?

Comment: table.languages is Qtable class that extends EntityPathBase<Table> and languages is column with type json that have only array of strings inside it (like in first screenshot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by:

- create function in DB using liqubase script:

```
        <createProcedure>
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_contains(array_jsonb jsonb, string_comma character varying )
            RETURNS bool
            LANGUAGE plpgsql
            AS $$
            BEGIN
                RETURN arraycontains(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                (array_jsonb)::text,
                                '[',
                                '{'
                            ),
                            ']',
                            '}'
                        )::text[],
                        string_to_array(string_comma, ',')
                    );
            END;
            $$;
        </createProcedure>
```

- call this function in boolen template:

```java
             result.add(
                Expressions.booleanTemplate(
                    "FUNCTION('jsonb_array_contains',({0}),'"
                        + String.join(",", filter.languages)
                        + "') = true",
                    table.languages
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to this type of cast ([The CAST operator in PostgreSQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-cast-operator-in-postgresql)) and additionally replacing the cast to text[] with another `string_to_array`, so we have eliminated all the colons and square brackets the parser may choke on:

```sql
arraycontains(string_to_array(replace(replace(CAST({0} AS text),'[','{'),']','}'),','),string_to_array({1},',')) = true
```

Comment: after changing type casting to this way, nothing changed:(

Comment: I'm surprised that you don't get a different type of error, at least. My version gets past the parser, when run locally. I would have thought that perhaps it would have started to complain about any functions it can't find in the database.

Comment: I've tested different options with type casting and rewriting the entire sql-query, but hibernate always can't parse something like 'as', 'text[]' and other stuff. Helps only creating a custom function in DB and calling it (see my answer).

Comment: Apologies: I accidentally turned the text[] into a text. I've updated the answer to replace the cast to text[] with a call to `string_to_array`.